# How to wake a CentOS 7.8 machine remotely after running “systemctl suspend?”

Tags: centos-7, suspend

I have CentOS 7.8 installed on my server. I found out that after I run command `systemctl suspend`, the screen turns black and the SSH connection is lost, but the fan connected to the motherboard is still running.

And I cannot wake the system up by sending magic packet on LAN or press the power button.

How should I debug this problem?

Comment: So the problem is you would like to suspend the machine but be able to wake it up later on when you need it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.